# Do all of the Shazams have all of the powers?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, shazam-2019

When Billy's siblings get powers, each focuses on a different power. Do they each only get one, do they get some, or do they get all of the powers?

Answer (score 5):

**Unclear yet, but probably**

If they are following the Shazam familiy idea from the comics then his siblings will now have all of the powers he does. It's possible they didn't demonstrate all of the powers since they'd only just received them and would take time to learn how to use them.

I will note that having powers, but not having invulnerability, would be a bad thing for a superhero.